# Random row in Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am creating an app that involves questions and facts and I need them to be selected at random. There is going to be a ton of different ones and I do not want to have to type in the ObjectId for each one of them. Is there a way to get the ObjectId of a random row so I don't have to write in the object Id for each question or fact that is in the class?

Comment: You can create a random number with `arc4random` or `arc4random_uniform` depending what version of **swift** your using. and set the range between how far the number should be and assign the value of a random number to **object id**.

Answer (score 1):

Three steps to accomplish what you want:

1. Know ahead of time or find out the number of questions you have to look through.
2. Create a random integer using `arc4random()` or some other method between 0 and that number.
3. Create a `PFQuery` on your question class with `skip` set to the random integer and `limit` set to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function for retrieving your questions, only the first 1000, and saving them locally:

```
func saveAllObjectsLocally() {
    let query = PFQuery(className: “Questions”)
    query.limit = 1000
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects {
                do {
                    try PFObject.pinAllInBackground(objects)
                } catch let error as NSError? {
                    print("error \(error)")
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Once they are saved locally, a random question can be selected:

```
func getRandomQuestion() -> PFObject? {
    let query = PFQuery(className: “Questions”)
    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if let objects = objects {
            let randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(objects.count))
            return objects[Int(randomIndex)]
        }           
    }
    return nil
}
```

This is going to be faster than accessing the network every time a random question is needed.

If you need to access the questions from the cloud you can add an index column to your Parse database and use that as a key to efficiently retrieve a random row.